# Having trouble splitting words in java

Tags: java, regex, string

I have the following string:

```
String text = "stack Overflow, stack"
```

a char:

```
char c = "*"
```

and another string:

```
String word = "Overflow"
```

the whole idea is to check for the word "overflow" in the text string, and surround it with the char c. The output should look something like this:

```
"stack *Overflow*, stack"
```

First, in order to solve this, i thought of splitting the string into words, and then check for each word if it contains the desired string as a substring of itself. Then create a stringBuilder, and append the char on each end of the word. I get no erros, but a wrong output though:

```
"stack *Overflow,* stack
```

Any help on how to solve this properly ?

Answer (score 6):

This should do the trick..

```
text = text.replace(word, c + word + c);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
String text = "stack Overflow, stack";
char c = '*';
String repl = text.replaceAll("\\b(Overflow)\\b", c + "$1" + c);
//=> stack *Overflow*, stack
```